# Using WatchKit, how do I position a Label on top of an Image?

Tags: ios, watchkit

Using WatchKit, how do I position a Label on top of an Image?

See how the $201.00 is hovering over the Tesla logo?  How do you achieve that?  I can't figure out how to put things on top of each other in my WatchKit app storyboard.

[image: Example screenshot]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Judged by the corner radius of the background image, I would say putting the label into a group, and setting the backgroud image of that group.

Comment: Oh wow, totally didn't realize you can set the background image of a group.  Will try that now, and report back, thanks.