# How do I place a button inside of an image?

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-watch, xcode-6.2

Is it possible to place a UIButton inside of a UIImage with the Apple Watch? It seems that I can only place objects beside each other rather then on top of them as I can with iOS

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you can't really place items on top of each other with WatchKit, but you can use the background image of a group to do it:

> **Can I position interface elements on top of each other?**
>
> No, interface elements can’t be positioned on top of each other natively. However, there are workarounds. For example, you can use a WKInterfaceGroup and set its background image to something that represents the control you want to overlay. Inside the group you can then add the necessary labels, buttons and so on.

This comes from [Ray Wenderlich's WatchKit FAQ](http://www.raywenderlich.com/94672/watchkit-faq), which is a pretty reliable source. I'll link to fully official sources if I find it.

The solution is, as stated above, to **use a WKInterfaceGroup and set its background image to something that represents the control you want to overlay. Inside the group you can then add the necessary labels, buttons and so on.**

Note that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29068351/using-watchkit-how-do-i-position-a-label-on-top-of-an-image) also is about laying elements on top of images.

Comment: If our Apple watch app is going to swipe between different page views, can each have their own background?

Comment: Of course! On each page, create a WKInterfaceGroup, set the background image, and add your buttons..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can not do that.

**But** what you *can* do is to create a button and set it's backgroundImage.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: We were hoping to be able to swipe between different page views, each with their own background, containing buttons in the back ground. Is that possible?

Comment: Oh, well try to add a button to the `pageView`s.

Comment: I'm curious if the different page views can have their own separate background.

Comment: I don't know but I mean if every `pageView` can contain a button then you can set the button's backgroundImage.

Comment: Ouu, see we're getting close, but the image needs to contain two separate buttons